# Cucumber with Selenium not working getting runner error

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

Here is the code runner file:

```
package TestRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)                
@CucumberOptions(features="Features",glue={"StepDefinition"})                       
public class Runner                 
{       
}
```

and getting this error

[image]

Unable to get a resolution to solve this issue!

Comment: Is cucumber jar present in your project build path

Comment: yes its there in my build path

Comment: Only a guess. Try path names without blanks (`%20`) in it.

Comment: please post your console log.

Comment: console is blank

Comment: strange the blank spaces in the folder names was creating an issue now things are working i just need to correct the code....